# export JAVA_HOME with spaces in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, export, space, java-home

I'm trying to set my JAVA_HOME in Cygwin with this command:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_10"
```

But when I do `cd $JAVA_HOME`, I'd get this error:

```
$ cd $JAVA_HOME
-bash: cd: /cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

I tried quoting, and escaping the space (ie., `\`), but none worked.
Any idea what else would?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to quote the cd command: `cd "JAVA_HOME"`

Answer (score 17):

I faced this problem too and I saw many posts but nothing really worked. There is a small trick that I did and things started working.

My JAVA_HOME was set to C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_23.
The problem was with Program Files directory and I was getting the same error.

In Windows there is a short name created for every directory with a space which is without a space.
You can see it by running dir /X command on the command prompt.
The Short name for Program Files was PROGRA~1.

In the Windows env variable through My Computer I changed the JAVA_HOME to C:/PROGR~1/Java/jdk1.7.0_23 and in hadoop-env.sh I changed JAVA_HOME to /cygdrv/c/PROGRA~1/Java/jdk1.7.0_23.

It worked fine.

Comment: +1 - Just a note - you have to restart your cygwin session for the modified environment variable to be detected.

Comment: Note that "C:\Program Files (x86)" is "/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~2"

Answer (score 8):

You set `JAVA_HOME` correctly. Now let's `cd` correctly too.

```
cd "$JAVA_HOME"
```

Comment: What about `ls "$JAVA_HOME"`? And what's the new error message when it's not working?

Comment: And btw, is it 64-bit system? There is some kind of redirection of Program Files to Program Files (x86) involved, maybe cygwin 32-bit stuff just doesn't see your real Program Files at all.

Comment: Yes, there is a Program Files (x86), but I do have stuff in Program Files, too (for historic reasons). And the ls command returns the same error the cd command does.

Comment: You posted your command and error message when you `cd` without double quotes. Now post the same for `cd` with double quotes. Also try to check it element by element: does `ls "/cygrive/c/Program Files/"` show Java subdirectory?  What about `ls "/cygrive/c/Program Files/Java/"`? (The main thing to understand is that we already solved the problem with variable by using double quotes. What remains is a problem with filesystem).

Comment: This solution is not much use when the cd command is embedded in a script - for example one that starts tomcat. I don't want to edit tomcat scripts to get it working, a better solution is to use the windows short name although I feel that having to do this highlights a shortcoming in Cygwin more than anything else.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid using the tedious Windows environment variables, and also use the actual path string copied from Windows explorer, I suggest adding the following to your startup script:

```
             TMP=`cygpath -sw "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31"`
export JAVA_HOME=`cygpath -u $TMP`
```

The first `cygpath` invocation obtains a **s**hort, **w**indows path; the second converts it to **u**nix format, which works fine in cygwin.

This will also now work fine:

```
$ cd $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: Great solution! Thanks. I had to switch between Java 8 and Java 11, which is a nightmare on Windows. This post saved my day!.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use short name to avoid a space in a path.

"C:\Program Files" should have short name C:\Progra~1 (you can verify it using DOS dir command or entering it into address bar in file explorer).

Set your JAVA_HOME this way:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/Java/jdk1.7.0_10"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the DOS subst command to take the spaces of the JAVA_HOME  path name.
Assuming   drive J; is not mounted or otherwise used.

In a DOS shell

```
subst j: "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45"
```

J:  is now an abbreviation for C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45

You can now cd to J:

now run Cygwin and

```
export JAVA_HOME="J:"
```

Answer (score 1):

I installed Java outside of "Program Files", specifically in c:\tools.  Then you can use cygpath to convert the C:\tools\jdk1.8.0_144 to /cygdrive/c/tools/jdk1.8.0_144

Comment: And if you can't choose your install directory, use cygwin to make a soft-link, where the link's path has no spaces, and set JAVA_HOME to that.

Answer (score 0):

on **MSYS2** terminal

checke for previous claim:
`ls "/C/program files/"` !works!  -thats for long file names so, to the point:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/D/Devel/jdk-12.0.2"
```

And now maven works....

check:

```
user55@DESKTOP MSYS ~
# echo $JAVA_HOME
/D/Devel/jdk-12.0.2
```