# AEM(CQ) 5.6 is not woking in Java 1.8.0_111?

Tags: java, aem

I'm new to AEM(CQ), I've installed two version in my machine like AEM 5.6 and 6.2. version 6.2 is working fine in java 1.8.0_111 but 5.6 is not working. Can you please advise how use both version in a system?

Comment: And what are the errors? _5.6 is not working_ is very vague statement.

Comment: the following error I've in AEM 5.6: 

Error:

Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred at line: 95 in the jsp file: /libs/granite/core/components/login/login.jsp The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AEM 5.6 does not support JVM 8.x as per the [official document](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/deploying/technical_requirements.html#Java%20Virtual%20Machines).

AEM 5.6.1 is the first version to add support for JVM 8.x starting from [SP2](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/deploying/technical_requirements.html#Java%20Virtual%20Machines).

Comment: Is there a way to run both version?

Comment: Now i have installed two 1.7 & 1.8 versions of java.

Comment: Are you using java 7 to run AEM 5.6? If you use default java, the java 8 might be used and the error you are getting is from java 8 so make sure you give absolute path to java /jdk/1.7/../java -jar crx-*** to run AEM 5.6

Comment: The following path, I have given: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: You mean like C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe -jar cq-quickstart-5.6.jar, also can you use java.exe to see more errors?

Comment: Yes, of course it shows more errors. Even I've changed  environment variable but it show same

Comment: I think you have an issue with Java version that is being picked up for AEM... Look at this thread for some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324486/properly-installing-java-8-along-with-java-7

Answer (score 0):

You could use virtual box or docker to run multiple instances each having its own dedicated environment.

For docker based environments you can find the image on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com) (search for AEM)

For Virtual box, you could use Vagrant and Virtualbox for provisioning - refer to provisioning script [here](https://github.com/ameeshtrikha/aem-vagrant), this allows to customize java and aem version within the configuration YAML